# Easy way to switch out web references with sharpdevelop on .net deployment?

Tags: .net, deployment

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a possibly GUI free way of switching out local web references to production ones.

I am developing using SharpDevelop. The 'seams' I see are the web references folder, however I've been running into issues swapping them out by a simple copy and paste.

I'm considering writing a script using autoit that manually deletes and adds web references, but I thought I'd first ask here before spending the time.

Thanks for any tips,

Dane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

Have a deployment folder that mirrors the structure of the deployment folder.

If there have been no changes in the web interfaces, then the folder containing the project for the web services should be unchanged.

So simply leave it there. Replace projects/folders that have changed.

Load the solution file in the deployment folder, rebuild everything.